# How can I quickly change a setting that is "deep" in a menu?

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to toggle  "Allow Wi-Fi Calls" all the time.  Currently I have to do the following.

Tap Settings.  Scroll down to phone. Tap.  Find Wi-Fi Calls.  Tap. Toggle switch.

That's SIX things I have to do to change one setting.  And I have to change it all the time.  Is there a shortcut?

Comment: So I'll ask the question. Why do you need to turn off wifi calling?  I'm not familiar with it, however I think that it would just not allow wifi calling if that method didn't work.